# Open CV3.1 Java Java java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, opencv

http://answers.opencv.org/question/68037/opencv-3-java-face-recognition-example-requested/

ここにあるサンプルコードを試そうと試みたのですが
タイトルの通り、以下の部分から `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`が返ります。

```
  CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(
   "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"
  );
```

インストールはopencvのページから最新版の３．１を落とし自分でビルドしました。
エラーは出ず、ライブラリも、jarファイルも作成されています。
環境はOS X 10.11.6です。

それなのに、エラーがかえるのはやはりビルドに失敗しているのでしょうか？

エラー詳細です。

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  
org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(CascadeClassifier.java:31)
at FaceDetectorTest.main(FaceDetectorTest.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) ```
````

色々調べると以下を忘れているケースが多いのですが

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

これは既に挿入した上でのエラーです。　上がない場合とはエラーが異なるのでビルドされたファイル自体は読みに行っていると思うのですが。。。

```
lib*.soにリンクしたlib*.dylibの指定もしています。
```

Comment: たぶんdylibが見つけれてないのだと思います。「dylibの指定もしています」とはどういうことでしょうか

Comment: 間違ったdylibの時と、あっている時でエラーが異なるので

Comment: 正しくパスの指定はできていると思われる、という意味でした。

Comment: わかりにくくてすいません。。例えば*.dylibを dylipにするとエラーが変わります。　やはりビルドが怪しそうですね。。

Comment: `System.loadLibrary(...);`をstaticブロックに入れて`static{System.loadLibrary(...);}`にしても同じですか？

Comment: だめでした。 ビルドからやり直してみます。